# raspberry pi IDLE software won't open

Tags: raspberry-pi

i have installed wheezy on my raspberry pi and everything works fine except for the IDLE software where both versions IDLE and IDLE 3 won't open when double clicking them from the desktop or from the start like menu.
i try to open them but nothing happens?!

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what does this have to do with this issue, but i used to connect to raspberry pi by putty and xming11 and at that case the IDLE software didn't open when trying to access it.
however by using tightvnc, this issue was solved!!!